# How can I create a line that is less than 1 unit in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm looking at the Google translate application on my phone (top image) and there's a line between each row of the settings that is very thin.

When I try to duplicate this line in Xamarin (bottom image 1 unit line)

```
<BoxView HeightRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
         BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource LineColor}" Margin="0" />
```

I cannot get this thickness.  I thought the minimum line width was 1 so how can Google manage to make a line that appears thinner and can I somehow do this in Xamarin?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't you simply set it to "0.1" or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`BoxView.HeightRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.heightrequest?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_VisualElement_HeightRequest) is `double`, you can freely set it to be less than 1.
For example:
`HeightRequest="0.1"`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting 0.2 for HeightRequest. HeightRequest type is double and Boxview will work with 0.2 as the minimum value for it. 
Code similar to

`<BoxView  BackgroundColor="Gray" HeightRequest="0.2"/>`